# Date in javascript isn't correct

Tags: javascript, reactjs, date, asynchronous

I'm currently trying to make a calendar with react js, here is the code generating the whole month

```
function getWholeMonth(curDate) {
    var ans = [];
    var focusDate = new Date(curDate);
    focusDate = new Date(focusDate.setDate(1));
    var startDate = new Date(focusDate);
    var endDate = new Date(focusDate);
    startDate = new Date(startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate() - startDate.getDay() + 1));
    endDate = new Date(endDate.setDate(endDate.getDate() + 7 - endDate.getDay()));
    for(var i = 0; ; i++) {
      if(startDate.getMonth() > focusDate.getMonth() || startDate.getFullYear() > focusDate.getFullYear()) {
        break;
      } 
      ans.push(<SingleWeek startDate = {startDate} endDate = {endDate}/>);
      startDate = new Date(startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate() + 7))
      endDate = new Date(endDate.setDate(endDate.getDate() + 7))     
      
    }
    return ans;
}
```

It seems to work properly for me, but the result I receive is the second week of the month is duplicated twice and the first week disappears like the image. (it seems to shift one week to the right answer).

[image]

The SingleWeek is the single row of the calendar, I have print the startDate and endDate before pushing the SingleWeek to the ans and the printed date seems correct but at the same time I print in the SingleWeek, it shows the totally different date

this is the singleweek code

```
function SingleWeek(props) {
  const {
    startDate,
    endDate
  } = props;
  var week = [];

  console.log("week", startDate, endDate)

  for(var i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    var curDate = new Date(startDate);
    curDate = new Date(curDate.setDate(curDate.getDate() + i))
    week.push(<SingleDay currentDate = {curDate}/>)
  }
  return (
    <div style = {{display: "flex"}}>
      {week}
    </div>
  );

}
```

Why does this happen and how to fix it?

thanks

Comment: What value is being passed to *curDate*?

Comment: it's a Date. Here is the code var wholeMonth = getWholeMonth(date);

Answer (score 0):

In your code:

```
function getWholeMonth(curDate) {
    var ans = [];
    var focusDate = new Date(curDate);
```

What value is being passed to *curDate*?

```
    focusDate = new Date(focusDate.setDate(1));
```

ECMAScript Dates are mutated by *set* calls, so the above is equivalent to:

```
    focusDate.setDate(1)
```

which sets *focusDate* to the first of the month.

```
    var startDate = new Date(focusDate);
    var endDate = new Date(focusDate);
    startDate = new Date(startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate() - startDate.getDay() + 1));
```

That can be:

```
    startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate() - startDate.getDay() + 1);
```

That will set *startDate* to the Monday on or before the date it is initially set to (which was the 1st of the month) **unless** it's initially set to Sunday, in which case it will be set to the following Monday (i.e. the 2nd of the month). You need to convert Sunday's day number to 7, so:

```
    startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate() - (startDate.getDay() || 7) + 1);
```

so that Sunday goes back to the previous Monday too.

```
    endDate = new Date(endDate.setDate(endDate.getDate() + 7 - endDate.getDay()));
```

Again:

```
    endDate.setDate(endDate.getDate() + 7 - endDate.getDay())
```

is sufficient. This has the same issue as the setting of *startDate* due to Sunday being zero, not 7. If *startDate* is set correctly, then you can copy that to *endDate* and just add 7 days.

```
    for(var i = 0; ; i++) {
      if(startDate.getMonth() > focusDate.getMonth() || startDate.getFullYear() > focusDate.getFullYear()) {
        break;
      } 
      ans.push(<SingleWeek startDate = {startDate} endDate = {endDate}/>);
      startDate = new Date(startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate() + 7))
      endDate = new Date(endDate.setDate(endDate.getDate() + 7))     
      
    }
```

The above is crying out to be a *while* loop:

```
    while (startDate.getMonth() <= focusDate.getMonth() &&
           startDate.getFullYear() <= focusDate.getFullYear()) {
      ...
    }
```

Below is a simpler block of code that returns all dates from the Monday on or before the start of the month to the Sunday on or after the last of the month. To get weeks, just slice into blocks of 7 days:

```js
function getFullMonth(focusDate) {
  // Copy passed in Date
  let startDate = new Date(focusDate);
  // Set to 1st of month
  startDate.setDate(1);
  // Set to Monday on or before
  startDate.setDate(1 - (startDate.getDay() || 7) + 1);
  // Copy passed in date
  let endDate = new Date(focusDate);
  // Set to last day of month
  endDate.setMonth(endDate.getMonth() + 1, 0);
  // Set to Sunday on or after last of month
  endDate.setDate(endDate.getDate() + 7 - (endDate.getDay() || 7));
  // Get the dates
  let dates = [];
  do {
    dates.push(new Date(startDate));
    startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate() + 1);
  } while (startDate <= endDate)
  
  return dates;
}

function sliceIntoWeeks(dates) {
  let weeks = [];
  for (let i=0; i<dates.length; i+=7) {
    weeks.push(dates.slice(i, i+6));
  }
  return weeks; 
}

// Start on Sunday, 1 May 2022
let dates = getFullMonth(new Date(2022,4,1));
let weeks = sliceIntoWeeks(dates);
weeks.forEach((week, i) => {
  console.log(`Week ${i+1}`);
  week.forEach(d => console.log(d.toString()));
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I have also realized the issue with the Sunday 0 index. For the focusDate you mention at the beginning, somehow when I print it shows the timestamp instead of date so I put the new Date(focusDate) to make it become a date